# Laravel 4 Blade Form - How to include HTML tag value?

Tags: html, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to update a record with the following:
    {{ Form::open(array('action' => array('RecZoneController@update', [zoneid]))) }}
where [zoneid] is the currently selected option of a select with id=zone.

I'm (obviously) new at this. I've searched in circles and can't seem to figure out this simple problem.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried removing that [zoneid] since in there documentation they actually pass a var... And in the action get from the post or get request!

Comment: I don't have [zoneid] in my code - that's a placeholder for what I can't figure out - how to correctly use the value of an html tag in place of [zoneid].

Comment: It is a normal post form you don't have to manually pass that to the form. Post is also the default so you don't have to set the method either. Just get the $_POST data in the action.

Comment: it's hard to help without the full source code

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should look for example...

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => 'SomeController@update')) }}
    {{ Form::select('myselect', array(1 => 'True', 0 => 'False')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

In the Controller action update...

```
public function update() {
    $post = Input::get('myselect');
    // Do whatever you need to do with it...
}
```

The way you are speaking of I believe is handled this way...

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('SomeController@update', $user->id))) }}
    {{ Form::select('myselect', array(1 => 'True', 0 => 'False')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Then the controller would be like this... I am at work so I cannot test it!

```
// See how the argument passed to the method is the $user->id
public function update($userId) {
    $post = Input::get('myselect');
    // Do whatever you need to do with it... and $userId
}
```

But in the controller action that handles the view of the  form

```
public function createForm() {
    $user = User::all();
    View::make('myform', array('user' => $user));
}
```

Also make sure for the update action you set the route for it like so

```
Route::post('/update/{userId}', 'SomeController@update');
```